# Image not match item in listview when search with SearchView Android

Tags: android, listview, fragment, searchview

I have listview in fragment populated from Activity with bundle , i have custom baseadapter and custom object with image and text , listview work fine with image and text , but when i do search with searchview i can get text and it's position and onclicklistener is ok without any problem, the issue is that i can't have image(logos ) with the correcte item(texttitle) , images is ranged by it's own position and not item text position

First here is my Custom object

```
public class Channel {

public String name;
public String logoUrl;

public Channel(String name, String logoUrl) {
    this.name = name;
    this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Channel {" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", logoUrl='" + logoUrl + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLogoUrl() {
    return logoUrl;
}

public void setLogoUrl(String logoUrl) {
    this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
}
```

}

and here is my custom Base Adapter

```
public class ChannelAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

private Activity context;
private ArrayList<Channel> channelNames = new ArrayList<>(); //mList
private ArrayList<Channel> channelLogos = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Channel> tmpNames= null;
private ArrayList<Channel> tmpLogos= null;

private CustomFilter myFilter = new CustomFilter();
ColorSpace.Model model;




public ChannelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Channel> channels, ArrayList<Channel> logos){


    this.context = (Activity) context;
    this.channelNames = channels;
    this.channelLogos = logos;
    this.tmpNames = channels;
    this.tmpLogos = logos;


    //    Names.addAll(channelLogos);



}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // return Names.size();
    return tmpNames.size();

}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return String.valueOf(tmpNames.get(position));
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row =null;
    if(convertView==null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent, Boolean.parseBoolean(null));


    }else{

        row=convertView;
    }

    TextView textView= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textv);
    ImageView image=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    textView.setText((CharSequence) tmpNames.get(position));


    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(String.valueOf(tmpLogos.get(position)))
            .into(image);

    return row;
}



@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if (myFilter == null) {
        myFilter = new CustomFilter();
    }
    return myFilter;
}

public class CustomFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final ArrayList<Channel> list = channelNames; //remettre channelNames

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = String.valueOf(list.get(i));
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }
        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }




    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Names.clear();
        // addAll((List<Channel>) results.values);
        tmpNames = (ArrayList<Channel>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

}

and finaly my OnqueryTextChange

```
 @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            ((ChannelAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(newText.toString());

        }
    });
```

Please need help if possible and thank's in advance

Comment: Thank's for quick reply , please have you some example with image and text coming from Url with arraydapter ?

Comment: Please pskink do you have example with more details ?

Comment: Thank's i will try it

Comment: Sorry no way to make it working , any suggestions or help please ?

Comment: Hello pskink , same problem i can't get image in the good position with text items , and i can't make MatchableArrayAdapter working too , i don't find way to modify onBind and matches methodes , i now it's easy for someone but  i'm just newbe on android devellopement ,please any help will be apreciated if possible of course

Comment: please just a question , when i extend my Adapter to MatchableArrayAdapter must i use filterable class too in my custom adapter or it's no need ? here is my matche method on MatchableArrayAdapter       protected boolean matches(T value, CharSequence constraint, CharSequence lowerCaseConstraint) {
        if (value instanceof Matchable) {
            return ((Matchable) value).matches(constraint, lowerCaseConstraint);
        }
        return value.toString().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseConstraint);
    }

Comment: i think matchable is tmpName, beacause i use it in my customadapter to store temporary search item and tmpLogos for image

Comment: You a are great person pskink thank you i will try it and feed back thank you very much have nice day

Comment: Hello now i have  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to dz.test.test.Channel
                                                                            at dz.test.test.ChannelAdapter.onBind(ChannelAdapter.java:12)
                                                                            at dz.test.test..MatchableArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(MatchableArrayAdapter.java:424)
                                                                            at dz.test.test.MatchableArrayAdapter.getView(MatchableArrayAdapter.java:386) thank you in advance

Comment: i have e beginning of class public class ChannelAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<Channel>

Comment: i post it all my adapter class

Comment: i just add my adapter class as an answer in the bottom sorry

Comment: When i click on page 12 error it send me to public class ChannelAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<Channel>

Comment: it send me at the begining of ChannelAdapter class it seem that Channel object not recognized or error on it

Comment: here is line 12 on ChannelAdapter "public class ChannelAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<Channel> ", that's what i have in line 12 on ChannelAdapter java class

Comment: Onbind method id defined at Line 19

Comment: and Constructor at line 14 and matches method on line 30

Comment: yes i have this exeption on logcat  ChannelAdapter.onBind(ChannelAdapter.java:12) exact

Comment: where i can get full stacktrace please

Comment: i put full logcat android studio as an answer in bottom sorry

Comment: here how i instantiate my ChannelAdapter "ChannelAdapter adaptersearch = new ChannelAdapter(getActivity(), channels);" , it is in Fragment not in Activity

Comment: Channel is "ArrayList<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<Channel>();", and comming from other Activity like that "channels = (ArrayList<Channel>) getArguments().getSerializable("chaines");"

Comment: i use "getSerializable" beacause i have an activity that get theses datas "channels and logos" from url and send it to second activity wich send it to fragments

Comment: did you try my code? it works without any problems right? no class casts, no errors - it simply works just fine

Comment: Ok pskink i will try it and feed back great thank's

Answer (score 0):

here is my adapter class

```
public class ChannelAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<Channel>{

    private Activity context;
    private ArrayList<Channel> channelNames = new ArrayList<>(); //mList
    private ArrayList<Channel> channelLogos = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Channel> tmpNames= new ArrayList<Channel>();
    private ArrayList<Channel> tmpLogos= null;

     boolean notifyChanged = false;

     public ChannelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Channel> channels, 
     ArrayList<Channel> logos){
        super(context, 0, channels);


        this.context = (Activity) context;
        this.channelNames = channels;
        this.channelLogos = logos;
        this.tmpNames = channels;
        this.tmpLogos = channels;


        //    Names.addAll(channelLogos);




    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // return Names.size();
        return channelNames.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Channel getItem(int position) {
        return channelNames.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row =null;
        if(convertView==null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent, Boolean.parseBoolean(null));


        }else{

            row=convertView;
        }
       //  TextView textView = null;
        TextView textView= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textv);
      //  ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textv)).getText().toString();
        ImageView image=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        textView.setText((CharSequence) channelNames.get(position));




        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(String.valueOf(channelLogos.get(position)))
                .into(image);

        return row;
    }



    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<Channel> results = new ArrayList<Channel>();
                if (channelNames == null)
                    channelNames = tmpNames;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (channelNames != null && channelNames.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Channel g : channelNames) {
                            if (g.getName().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(g);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                tmpNames = (ArrayList<Channel>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyChanged = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class ChannelAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<Channel> {

  public ChannelAdapter(Context context, List<Channel> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row, objects);
}

@Override
protected void onBind(Channel item, View itemView, int position) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textv);
    tv.setText(item.getName());

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(iv.getContext())
            .load(item.getLogoUrl())
            .into(iv);
}

@Override
protected boolean matches(Channel value, CharSequence constraint, 
CharSequence lowerCaseConstraint) {
    return value.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseConstraint);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Channel {

private String name;
private String logoUrl;

public Channel(String name, String logoUrl) {
    this.name = name;
    this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Channel{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", logoUrl='" + logoUrl + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public String getName() {
    return String.valueOf(name);
}

public void setName(ArrayList<String> name) {
    this.name = String.valueOf(name);
}

public String getLogoUrl() {
    return String.valueOf(logoUrl);
}

public void setLogoUrl(ArrayList<String> logoUrl) {
    this.logoUrl = String.valueOf(logoUrl);
}
}
```